# Make Visual Studio not erase release folder for setup projects

Tags: svn, visual-studio, setup

This is a major pet peeve of mine. I use SVN and when I roll out a new version, I make a new setup for it. The "compile" behaviour for setup projects is different from most projects. Instead of the default:

```
bin/Debug
bin/Release
obj/Debug
obj/Release
```

There are simply two folders, Debug and Release. The setup compiles and deletes the Release folder, only to make a new Release folder and put the goods in them.

So naturally, this doesn't agree with SVN, as its .svn folder gets erased at every build.

Is there an option to instruct Visual Studio to NOT erase the folder, just the content?

FYI, this has been around in every version, from VS 2003 to 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the repository to Subversion 1.7 fixed this. the .svn directory is now only present in the root, so erasing and recreating a subdirectory is acceptable.